# How can I clip with the border and boxshadow

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have tried clipping but the full border cuts off from the clipped and the shadow disappears.

HTML CODE:

```
  <div className="text-center w-[400px] h-[450px] ml-auto box-border1 boxclip">
       <div className='w-[390px] h-[440px] py-6 '>
            <h1 className='text-4xl font-bold uppercase'>Game Testing</h1>
            <p className='px-12 font-semibold mt-6'>Game testing, a subset of game development, is a software testing process for quality control of video games. The primary function of game testing is the discovery and documentation of software defects. Interactive entertainment software testing is a highly technical field requiring computing expertise, analytic competence, critical evaluation skills, and endurance.</p>
  </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.box-border1 {
 border: 0.943723px solid #000000;
 box-shadow: -18px 14.1558px 0px #000000;
 }


.boxclip {
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 81%, 84% 100%, 50% 100%, 0 
 100%, 0% 70%, 0 15%, 15% 0);
 clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 81%, 84% 100%, 50% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 
 70%, 0 15%, 15% 0); 
 }
```

[image: This is I am getting]
[image: this it desired output image]

Comment: Can you drop in some code please? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: use drop-shadow instead of box-shadow

Comment: drop shadow does not work it drops all the element inside the div